# Two random variables with same moments

Tags: random-variables, moment-problem

Reading http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter10.pdf pages 368-370. it states "if we delete the hypothesis that have finite range in the above theorem, then the conclusion is no longer necessarily true".

So my question is

> Do you know a (simple?) example of two discrete random variables with
>   finite moments equal for each order but different distributions?

Comment: See 11.7 and 11.8 in Counterexamples in Probability: Third Edition, by Jordan M. Stoyanov. (This is called the moment problem and you should check keywords such as "Carleman's condition".)

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057663/does-mgf-determine-cdf

Comment: For example, for every integer $q\geqslant2$ and real number $|u|\leqslant1$, the formulas $$P(X_u=q^n)=e^{-q}q^n\left(\frac1{n!}+\frac{(-1)^nu}{(q-1)(q^2-1)\cdots(q^n-1)}\right)$$ define a family of random variables $(X_u)$ on the set $\{q^n\mid n\geqslant0\}$ with the same moments for every $u$. The distribution of $X_0$ is log-Poisson, meaning that $X_0=q^Y$ with $Y$ some Poisson random variable.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite what you're asking for, but a standard example of continuous random variables with the same moments yet distinct distributions is

$f_1(x) = e^{- (\log{x})^2/
2} \,
/ \,(x\sqrt{2\pi})$

$f_2(x) =
f_1(x)(1 + \sin(2
\pi
\log{x})/2)$

where $ x > 0$.